# css animate rotate property as linear transition

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

is it posible, to animate css `rotate` as linear transition (take start and end points of transition and use them like a keyframes where points go straight forward to their final position)?

for example:

[image: img_1]

by default rotation from `1` to `2` would go by circular way (blue one), but i want it to go from "point to point" (yellow one), but also keep it smooth (not make something like `steps(1)`)

Comment: Is it just a line you are trying to rotate in this way? Perhaps you could provide a small code example to make this plain. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I ask because there is a simple way to make it look as though this straight line effect is happening (by hiding the rest of the line) but that may not meet your actual real-life requirement (e.g. if you want the line to actually 'shrink').

Comment: Are you still interested in finding a solution for this which is smooth? If so, could you confirm that just not showing part of the line during the rotation would be sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the line to rotate with its end point following a straight line rather than round the arc of the circle you can place a solid color over the part you do not want displayed.

This snippet does this by using the before pseudo element of a div as the line and the after pseudo element (rotated about its bottom right hand corner) to hide the end of the line.

Using CSS rotation transform on the line with linear timing means the movement is linear.

This snippet adds the outer circle and the yellow line shows the cut off.

```css
.line {
  position: relative;
  --deg: 70deg;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  /* the following settings are just for the demo */
  border: solid blue 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: right center;
  animation: rot 5s linear alternate infinite forwards;
  z-index: -1;
}

.line::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -50%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: rotate(calc((var(--deg)) / 2));
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
  /* the following settings are just for the demo */
  border-right: solid 4px gold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes rot {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(var(--deg));
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you’re proposing to do is not possible with only rotation.

The path that needs to be traversed in a circle is always equidistant from the center point, or origin.

The path that needs to be traversed in your question involves scaling or translating the object being rotated.

**Edit**: More detailed explanation: If you measure the distance to a point on the circle from the origin, it is further than the distance to the midpoint on the line from the origin.

The scale needs to be equal to 1 at each point. The scale needs to be smaller at a keyframe exactly in between one point and the next. Or a similar solution if you are translating it instead.

The result is that you need to add a scaling transition between each rotate you already have and the scale back to 1 at your existing ones.

**Edit #2:** This is by no means perfect, but this is the basic idea. I would ideally write something like this in SCSS due to the math involved, but there's nothing like the basics.

The red circle is moving along the outer path of an invisible circle between 12 points like a clock.

For each half hour, I translate the red circle closer to the origin, then back out on the hour. This is what makes it appear as if it is taking a straight line from one point to the next.

Rotating the circle at normal speed and varying the distance to the center at just the right ratio will give you what you want.

Finding the right ratio depends on how many target points/keyframes rest along the circles edge. If you have half as many points as the clock example with 12, the midpoint of each line segment will be closer to the center and thus more translation is necessary in each frame. If you have more than 12, the midpoints will be further away than in the example.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #333;
}
@keyframes tick {
    0%     { transform: rotate(0)      translateX(100px); }
    4.16%  { transform: rotate(15deg)  translateX(98px); }
    8.32%  { transform: rotate(30deg)  translateX(100px); }
    12.48% { transform: rotate(45deg)  translateX(98px); }
    16.64% { transform: rotate(60deg)  translateX(100px); }
    20.8%  { transform: rotate(75deg)  translateX(98px); }
    24.96% { transform: rotate(90deg)  translateX(100px); }
    29.12% { transform: rotate(105deg) translateX(98px); }
    33.28% { transform: rotate(120deg) translateX(100px); }
    37.44% { transform: rotate(135deg) translateX(98px); }
    41.6%  { transform: rotate(150deg) translateX(100px); }
    45.76% { transform: rotate(165deg) translateX(98px); }
    49.92% { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(100px); }
    54.08% { transform: rotate(195deg) translateX(98px); }
    58.24% { transform: rotate(210deg) translateX(100px); }
    62.4%  { transform: rotate(225deg) translateX(98px); }
    66.56% { transform: rotate(240deg) translateX(100px); }
    70.72% { transform: rotate(255deg) translateX(98px); }
    74.88% { transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(100px); }
    79.04% { transform: rotate(285deg) translateX(98px); }
    83.2%  { transform: rotate(300deg) translateX(100px); }
    87.36% { transform: rotate(315deg) translateX(98px); }
    91.52% { transform: rotate(330deg) translateX(100px); }
    95.68% { transform: rotate(345deg) translateX(98px); }
    100%   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(100px); }
}
.box {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #a33;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 #222;
    animation: tick 6s linear infinite;
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: How would you implement the scaling (i.e. what is the formula for this?).

Comment: Hey @AHaworth. I’ll work something up tonight and post it as a runnable snippet. Taking care of my kids right now :)

Comment: @AHaworth I posted a runnable example of the effect.

Comment: So this isn't smooth? I thought you might be changing the scaling on a formula.

Comment: The formula is in the chosen pixel values. For a 12 sided shape, the translation value will vary between 98% and 100%. For a six sided shape, it varies between 96% to 100%. I don't know the exact formula off the top of my head, but I can include it. It involves getting the magnitude of each line segment, getting half the length, then finding the distance to the circle's edge from the line's midpoint.

Comment: @AHaworth I’m going to work up the formula to rotate by any arbitrary angle and smoothly follow the line segment it produces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyframes

```css
  body {
        position: relative;
    }

    #box1 {
        position: relative;
        animation: mymove 5s infinite;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        left: 200px;
        top: 100px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    @keyframes mymove {
        0% {
            left: 200px;
            top: 100px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        25% {
            left: 300px;
            top: 200px;
            transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        75% {
            left: 200px;
            top: 300px;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        100% {
            left: 100px;
            top: 200px;
            transform: rotate(270deg);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
```

Here you can learn more about keyframes : [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.php)

Comment: This answer completely failed to address the problem.

Comment: Please read the question. It's about moving an object linearly from point to point around a circle. This code example has absolutely nothing to do with that.